# Vue3 + quasar q-table cover style

Tags: vuejs3, quasar

I am currently using the QTable component from Quasar to create a table.

I have encountered an issue where I am using a button to control the visibility of certain columns.

However, when a column is not displayed,
I don't want it to occupy any space or inherit styles from previously rendered columns.

To address this, I have implemented a filteredData approach to determine which columns should be displayed based on certain conditions.

However, I have noticed that when the condition is met, the column is still affected by the styles applied to the previously rendered columns.

For example, if column[1] originally had no styling, it inherits the justify-center style from the previous column when an additional column is added before it.

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this requirement.

```
<template>
  <div class="col-grow flex column q-pa-lg">
    <q-btn
      v-if="!isSort"
      color="primary"
      outline
      icon="sort"
      class="q-btn-sm"
      size="16px"
      label="sort"
      unelevated
      @click="isSort = true"
      style="padding-left: 21px; padding-right: 21px"
    >
    </q-btn>
    <q-btn
      v-if="isSort"
      color="primary"
      outline
      class="q-btn-sm"
      size="16px"
      label="saveSort"
      unelevated
      @click="isSort = false"
      style="padding-left: 21px; padding-right: 21px"
    >
    </q-btn>
    <q-table
      :rows="isServiceSpeechRows"
      :columns="filteredData"
      flat
      table-header-class="text-no-wrap"
    >
      <template v-if="!isSort" v-slot:header-cell-toolbar="props">
        <q-th :props="props">
          <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
            <div class="">move</div>
          </div>
        </q-th>
      </template>
      <template v-if="!isSort" v-slot:body-cell-toolbar="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center items-center">
            <div class="flex no-wrap q-gutter-x-sm">
              <q-btn
                unelevated
                round
                size="10px"
                padding="4px"
                color="grey-2"
                text-color="grey-8"
                icon="edit"
              >
              </q-btn>
            </div>
          </div>
        </q-td>
      </template>
      <template v-if="isSort" v-slot:header-cell-drag="props">
        <q-th :props="props">
          <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center items-center">
            <div>Icon</div>
          </div>
        </q-th>
      </template>
      <template v-if="isSort" v-slot:body-cell-drag="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div>
            <q-icon
              style="color: rgba(166, 166, 166, 1)"
              name="drag_indicator"
            />
          </div>
        </q-td>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:body-cell-isServiceCnt="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div class="flex no-wrap justify-center items-center">
            <div class="flex no-wrap q-gutter-x-sm">
              {{ props.row.isServiceCnt }}
              <q-tooltip
                class="custom-tooltip-1"
                anchor="top middle"
                self="bottom middle"
              >
                {{ props.row.isServiceAgentName }}
              </q-tooltip>
            </div>
          </div>
        </q-td>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:body-cell-date="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div class="flex column text-black-087">
            <span>{{ props.row.date }}</span>
            <div>{{ props.row.lastEdit }}</div>
          </div>
        </q-td>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:body-cell-isService="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div style="max-width: 35vw; width: 100%">
            {{ props.row.isService }}
          </div>
        </q-td>
      </template>
    </q-table>
  </div>
</template>
    <script setup>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

import { useMeta } from "quasar";
const isServiceSpeechColumns = [
  {
    name: "drag",
    align: "left",
    label: "",
    field: "drag",
    classes: "text-no-wrap",
    style: "width:48px;",
  },
  {
    name: "sort",
    align: "left",
    label: "sort",
    field: "sort",
    style: "width:56px",
    classes: "text-no-wrap",
  },

  {
    name: "isService",
    align: "left",
    label: "Name",
    field: "isService",
    style: "min-width:532px;",
  },
  {
    name: "isServiceCnt",
    align: "left",
    label: "Count",
    field: "isServiceCnt",
    style: "min-width:120px;",
  },
  {
    name: "date",
    align: "left",
    label: "date",
    field: "date",
    sortable: true,
    style: "width:180px",
    classes: "text-no-wrap",
  },

  { name: "toolbar", align: "right", field: "toolbar" },
];

const isServiceSpeechRows = [
  {
    sort: "1",
    isService: "101",
    isServiceCnt: "15",
    date: "2023/06/28 11:33",
    lastEdit: "Louis",
  },
  {
    sort: "2",
    isService: "BigMac",
    isServiceCnt: "200",
    date: "2023/06/28 12:33",
    lastEdit: "siuoL",
    isServiceAgentName: "LOUIS、SUOUWE、QWEQF、ASDD1123、ISME123FF",
  },
];
const isSort = ref(true);
const filteredData = computed(() => {
  return isServiceSpeechColumns.filter((column) => {
    return (
      (isSort.value || column.name !== "drag") &&
      (!isSort.value || column.name !== "toolbar")
    );
  });
});
</script>
```

I apologize for any confusion caused. English is not my primary language. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Best regards.

I would like to prevent it from breaking the layout.